# How do I save a document as .doc in Pages 5.2 not .docx?

Tags: macos

I have OSX10.9 and pages 5.2 and want to save the document in Pages as a *.doc. I can already export it as *.docx. I need help as to how to export or save it as *.doc?

Answer (score 1):

To save **Pages** document as `.doc` (compatible with Word 1997-2004), You need to: `File` -> `Export to` -> `Word...`, open "Advanced options" and pick `.doc`.

Here's article on OSXDaily about that: http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/06/save-pages-file-as-word-format/

Image from their site:
[image]